# Convert serde_json Value keys to camelCase

Tags: json, rust, serde, serde-json

I'm writing a CLI tool that reads JSON files and is supposed to convert the JSON object keys into camelCase.

Because this should work with any JSON file, I obviously can't just use strong typing and then `#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]`.

I can't seem to find an obvious way in `serde_json` to make it use the already existing renaming code that `serde` clearly has and apply it to a `serde_json::value::Value`.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: The renaming/lowercasing is done by the derive macro at compile time, not when parsing the JSON at runtime. See https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/blob/master/serde_derive/src/internals/case.rs#L12-L84

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to write a function that recurses through the `serde_json::Value` structure and replaces the keys of `serde_json::Map` whenever it encounters one. That's a bit awkward to implement, as there is no `Map::drain`.

```rust
fn rename_keys(json: &mut serde_json::Value) {
    match json {
        serde_json::Value::Array(a) => a.iter_mut().for_each(rename_keys),
        serde_json::Value::Object(o) => {
            let mut replace = serde_json::Map::with_capacity(o.len());
            o.retain(|k, v| {
                rename_keys(v);
                replace.insert(
                    heck::ToLowerCamelCase::to_lower_camel_case(k.as_str()),
                    std::mem::replace(v, serde_json::Value::Null),
                );
                true
            });
            *o = replace;
        }
        _ => (),
    }
}

use std::io::Read;
fn main() {
    let mut stdin = vec![];
    std::io::stdin()
        .read_to_end(&mut stdin)
        .expect("Read stdin");
    let mut json = serde_json::from_slice::<serde_json::Value>(&stdin).expect("Parse Json");
    rename_keys(&mut json);
    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string_pretty(&json).unwrap());
}
```

(Note that `rename_keys` will produce a stack overflow on deep JSON structures, but `serde_json` only parses to a limited depth by default, so no need to worry. If you do need support for deeply nested structures, have a look at [`serde_stacker`](https://docs.rs/serde_stacker/latest/serde_stacker/).)

---

If you're not interested in the `serde_json::Value` itself and just want to transform a JSON string, there's two more ways to go on about this:

- You could do the renaming on serialization, by writing a custom serializer for a wrapper struct around `serde_json::Value`. An example of such a serializer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70783569/serde-overwriting-child-structs-serderename-all-camelcase/70788255#70788255), but you'd have to adopt it to be recursive. (Possibly, doing it at deserialization might be easier than at serialization)
- Write a JSON tokenizer (or grab a crate that contains one - struson, e.g., but its API is awkward for this) to skip creating the actual `serde_json::Value` structure and to the renaming on the token stream (no need to worry when working with GBs of JSON)

Comment: Ok great. That confirms that I was not missing anything obvious :) Thank you so much for the very complete answer that covers all complexities and then some more!